# Как в Intellij Idea создать исполняемые файл для x32 и x64 систем?

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

сама IDE х64 как и jdk. Построил артифакт и исполняемый файл получил, все работает на моей ОС. Но на системах x32, на windows XP например не запускается, т к не является x32. Если я установлю IDE x32 и jdk аналогичную и проделаю тоже самое, то я получу то, что я жду? Или можно сделать на x64 для обеих систем?
Само приложение на javafx, если это важно вдруг.
СПасибо!

Answer (score 1):

эм.. java мультиплатформенная. Т.е. вы что-то пишите 1 раз и оно должно работать везде. java код компилируется в байт код для jvm а она уже его исполняет. 
Как можно догадаться jvm на машине стоит подходящая, не подходящую поставить сложно.

Скорее всего проблема именно в  исполняемом файле. Java приложения собираются в jar архивы, которые можно запускать на любой машине с jvm.

Попробуйте собрать свой проект в jar и запустить его на всех нужных вам машинах. Если ошибка повторится, тут хз. Если ошибка уйдет, значит проблема в исполняемом файле.

PS.. IDE не влияет не сборку проекта

Comment: Если ошибка появится, то лучше сюда выложить стек. А так, вероятно, кроме отличия (x32/x64) у вас отличаются версии java (например, проект написан на 1.8, а на XP установлена более низкая)

Comment: Есть же вроде понятие native package, исполняемый файл получается вместе с jvm, т. е. в папке все что нужно есть и вроде не нужно установленной jvm на машине клиенте, хотя я могу ошибаться..

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже рассматривался. [См. тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983169/bundle-jre-along-with-executable-jar)